# Java: Caesar Cipher won't println

Tags: java, encryption

The code compiles fine, but it does not print anything in the end. I'm new to coding and have been working on this for hours and am at a wall.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class caesartwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String originalText;
    int shiftValue; 

    //encryption
        System.out.println("What text would you like to encrypt?");
        originalText=keyboard.nextLine();

        //shift value
        System.out.print("\nWhat is the shift value? ");
        shiftValue=keyboard.nextInt();

        //encrypted string
        String encryptedText=encrypt(originalText,shiftValue);

        //print result
        System.out.println("\nThe encrypted text is:\n" + encryptedText);
    }
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) { 
    String convertedText = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
    char lowerLetter = userString.charAt(i);

    //uppercase conversion
    char upperLetter = Character.toUpperCase(lowerLetter);
    int charNumber = upperLetter;

    //shift and wrap
    int rotateShift = (charNumber + shiftValue) % 26;
    char shiftLetter = (char) rotateShift;

    //shifted chars
    convertedText += shiftLetter;
    }
  return convertedText;
}
public static String encrypt(String userString, int shiftValue) {
    String encryptedString = rotate(userString , shiftValue);
    return encryptedString;
}
}
```

Now I have to write some more words because I have too much code text blah blah blah.

Answer (score 3):

You've got some blur going on with your variables in your `rotate()` method. You should extract them and make them instance variables instead of letting each iteration of the loop create new variables. You can do this much simpler. Replace your rotate method with the below:

```
public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) { 
    String convertedText = "";
    int offset = shiftValue % 26 + 26;
    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
        j = (userString.charAt(i) - 'a' +offset) % 26;
        convertedText += (char) (j+'a');
    }
  return convertedText;
}
```

Tested it and it spits out a value now. Highjacked the algorithm from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Java

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here.

```
char shiftLetter = (char) rotateShift;
```

shiftletter never gets assigned a value when I debug through the code. Learn to debug your code and you'll be able to find an offending statement quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line `rotateShift = (charNumber + shiftValue) % 26;`. I understand that you're trying to wrap the ASCII value around so that if you shift 'Z' by one you get 'A'. However, on the ASCII table, 'A' begins at 65. Modding `(charNumber + shiftValue)` by 26, the answer could only be a number between 0 and 25 inclusive. And if you look at the ASCII table, 0-25 are all special characters that aren't printable like the NULL character and CARRIAGE RETURN. To ensure the desired result, I suggest adding `(charNumber + shiftValue) % 26` by 65 so that you start at 'A' and won't exceed 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

It won't print because of this line

```
int rotateShift = (charNumber + shiftValue) % 26
```

it will return 0-25 which is not mapped to english character in ASCII

you should do

```
int rotateShift = (charNumber - (int)('A') + shiftValue) % 26+ (int)('A');
```